# How to change the media attribute of a css file with plain JS

Tags: javascript, css

To avoid blocking the rendering of the "above the fold content" of a site one options seems to be using a css file with a bogus media. Browsers will download it asynchronously anyway as the media "could" apply later...

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="bogus">
</head>
```

Now, one way to get the CSS in place would be a link (with the proper media screen) at the very end of the body tag but i'd rather look at JS options.

**Question:** How do we change the media `bogus` using plain JS (no jQuery, no frameworks)

Comment: doesn't `document.querySelector('link').setAttribute('media', 'screen');` work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the *steps* you can follow:

1. Add an `id` to the `<link />` tag.

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="bogus" id="myLink" />
   ```
2. Use the following JavaScript (either one of the lines):

   ```
   document.getElementById("myLink").setAttribute("media", "screen");
   document.querySelector("#myLink").setAttribute("media", "screen");
   document.querySelectorAll("link")[0].setAttribute("media", "screen");
   ```

My recommendation is to better add an `id` and then call using it.

Comment: Why didn't I think of an ID on a link - brilliant, thanks.